# How to type Actions for Redux-Observable's Epics with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I'm setting TypeScript and Redux-Observable in my app and have this simple flow I'd like to apply here with an Epic:

```
dispatch('someAction')
fetch('relevant-endpoint-from-api')
getResponse(dispatch('someActionSuccess'))
failed(dispatch('someActionFailed'))
```

So following [this article](https://techinscribed.com/clean-react-architecture-with-redux-immer-typescript-redux-observable/) that is just doing that, I gave it a try.

Here's my actions.ts file:

```
export interface MediasOrigin {
  id: number;
  label: string;
  url: string;
  zonesId: number[];
  scenariosRef: number[];
  stepsRef: number[];
  gearsId: number[];
  texturesId: number[];
}

export enum MediasActionTypes {
  MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL = "MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL",
  MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS = "MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS",
  MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_FAILED = "MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_FAILED"
}

export interface IMediasOriginsFetchAllAction {
  type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL;
}

export interface IMediasOriginsFetchAllSuccessAction {
  type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL;
  payload: {
    medias: MediasOrigin[]
  }
}

export interface IMediasOriginsFetchAllFailedAction {
  type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL;
  payload: {
    error: string
  }
}

/* ACTION CREATOR */
export function fetchAllMediaOrigins(): IMediasOriginsFetchAllAction {
  return {
    type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL
  }
}

export type MediasAction = IMediasOriginsFetchAllAction | IMediasOriginsFetchAllSuccessAction | IMediasOriginsFetchAllFailedAction
```

And then my epic.ts file:

```
import { from, Observable, of } from "rxjs"
import { map, catchError, switchMap, filter } from "rxjs/operators"
import { isOfType } from "typesafe-actions"
import { Epic } from "redux-observable"

import ApiClient from "agent" // change, wrapper around superagent (http client)
import {IStore} from "reducers"
import {
  MediasAction,
  MediasActionTypes,
  IMediasOrigin
} from "./actions"

const getAllMediasOriginEpic: Epic<MediasAction, MediasAction, IStore> = action$ => {
  const request = new ApiClient();

  return action$.pipe(
    filter(isOfType(MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL)),
    switchMap(action => // change
      from(request.getAllOriginMedias()).pipe( // change
        map((response: IMediasOrigin[]) // change =>
          of({
            type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
            payload: { medias: response },
          })
        ),
        catchError((error: Error) // change =>
          of({
            type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_FAILED,
            payload: {error: Error.message}, // change
          })
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

export default combineEpics(getAllMediasOriginEpic)
```

I'm new to TypeScript so maybe the error seems obvious to aficionados, but I don't get what I've done wrong based on TypeScript's message.

(no longer relevant) The message points at the `action$` returned in the epic:

```
Type 'Observable<IMediasOriginsFetchAllAction | Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: unknown; }; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MediasAction>'.
  Type 'IMediasOriginsFetchAllAction | Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: unknown; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'MediasAction'.
    Type 'Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: unknown; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'MediasAction'.
      Type 'Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: unknown; }; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'IMediasOriginsFetchAllSuccessAction': type, payload  TS2322
```

I don't get what I could do to fix this, from the message it seems that all I've done is wrong and that medias is unknown although it's specified as being an array of `MediasOrigin` in the interface. Am I missing something here?

For information, here are the packages versions:

- typescript: 4.0.2
- redux-observable: 1.2.0
- rxjs: 6.6.3

### // Edit: 09/24/2020

I made a couple changes in order to make it simpler and got why the error message was talking about a mediasUnknown: I wasn't telling in the epic that response mapped from the api call was of `MediasOrigin[]` (renamed IMediasOrigin[] now). Also I removed the `api` method that was a custom operator of my own. Changes have been brought to the scripts above and signaled with a `// change` comment.

Here's now the error message:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/utopiad/Dev/spectral-core/platform/src/components/Medias/epics.ts(11,7):
Type '(action$: ActionsObservable<MediasAction>) => Observable<Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: IMediasOrigin[]; }; }> | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type 'Epic<MediasAction, MediasAction, IStore, any>'.
  Type 'Observable<Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: IMediasOrigin[]; }; }> | { type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { ...; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MediasAction>'.
    Type 'Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: IMediasOrigin[]; }; }> | { type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'MediasAction'.
      Type 'Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: IMediasOrigin[]; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'MediasAction'.
        Type 'Observable<{ type: MediasActionTypes; payload: { medias: IMediasOrigin[]; }; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'IMediasOriginsFetchAllFailedAction': type, payload
```

From what I get, it seems like there is a conflict between my IMediasOriginsFetchAllSuccessAction and IMediasOriginsFetchAllFailedAction at the payload level which makes one of them not assignable to type MediasAction. But isn't that the whole purpose of the | operator when creating types?

Comment: What if you add `mergeAll()` immediately after `api('...')`. The reason is that `api` itself creates an observable, which you haven't subscribed to yet, meaning that the next `map` operator in the chain would receive the observable, instead of its actual results.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, unfortunately I made changes since then and removed the `api` operator that was one my own. All changes have been reflected in the original post.

Comment: I think it's the same problem. Your `map` operator returns an observable `of(...)`. Try to remove `of()` and simply return the object `{
            type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
            payload: { medias: response },
          }` from it.

Comment: It adds two lines to the error message: `Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type 'MediasActionTypes' is not assignable to type 'MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL'.`

Comment: Could you reproduce the error in a StackBlitz or something similar?

Comment: Yep, I reproduced it here on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epics-and-typescript-9uigq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by adding `as const` to your `MediasActionTypes.*` when returning actions:

```js
const getAllMediasOriginEpic: Epic<MediasAction, MediasAction> = (action$) => {
  const request = new ApiClient();
  return action$.pipe(
    filter(isOfType(MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL)),
    switchMap((action) =>
      from(request.getAllOriginMedias()).pipe(
        map((response: IMediasOrigin[]) => ({
          type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS as const,
          payload: { medias: response }
        })),
        catchError((error: Error) =>
          of({
            type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_FAILED as const,
            payload: { error: error.message }
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
};
```

This is because when you use something like this:

```js
map((response: IMediasOrigin[]) => ({
    type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
    payload: { medias: response }
  })),
```

The Observable's type is: `{ type: MediasActionTypes }, ...`. As you've seen in your error

```js
Type 'MediasActionTypes' is not assignable to type 'MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_FAILED'
```

`'MediasActionTypes'` refers to a union and `MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_FAILED` to a **concrete** type. So, by using `type: MediasActionTypes.MEDIAS_ORIGINS_FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS as const` you're narrowing the type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it did indeed resolve my issue.

Comment: I’m glad I could help!